# ¿Como hacer un acceso directo de mi sistema en localhost?

Tags: php

Saludos, quiero hacer un acceso directo en mi escritorio de mi sistema que corre en localhost. Que ese acceso directo me lleve al index.php! A quien sepa de esto, gracias.

Comment: Hola Alejo, te invito a realizar el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos, además te sugiero leer [ask] para crear preguntas de calidad y que sean mejor recibidas.

Answer (score 3):

Primero que todo debes poner a correr tu servidor te recomiendo `Xampp` o `Wamp`.

Una vez tengas corriendo el `Servidor HTTP Apache` de tu servidor puedes buscar en las siguientes carpetas:

**Esto para el caso de Xampp**

- Windows: `"C:/xampp/htdocs/index.php"`
- Linux: `"/opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php"`

Ahí está el archivo `index.php` por defecto. Puedes eliminarlo y poner tu propio archivo index.php. Sin embargo lo recomendable es crear una carpeta en `/htdocs`

Para ver el resultado ingresas al siguiente link: http://localhost/
Si creaste una nueva carpeta ingresas `http://localhost/nombre_carpeta/`

---

## **NOTA:**

- Por defecto si solo pones el nombre de la carpeta va dirigirse al
  `index.php`, si deseas acceder a otro archivo especifico escribirías el
  nombre del archivo despúes del nombre de la carpeta
- Mucho cuidado con abrir los archivos directamente desde la carpeta,
  pues así no va funcionar. Debes poner a correr el servidor en
  ingresar a la página http://localhost/

Answer (score 0):

En Windows, creas un acceso directo en el escritorio y en el campo donde ira la ubicación a la que da acceso pones: http://localhost/

Ya lo tienes creado, solo tendrás que arrancar tu servidor para que funcione.

Un saludo.